# Ajax Return data Do not repeat content in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When you click the button when the display of a content, and then click the button when the content hidden, and then click the button when the show repeat, I do not know how to solve the problem? Big god can help solve? Thank you very much!

HTML file

```
<button id="liuyan" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">my click</button><div id="mydiv2">
```

JavaScript file

```
    $("button#liuyan").on("click", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/comment',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            async: false, 
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            var mydiv2 = $("#mydiv2");

            if (mydiv2.css("display") === "none") {
                mydiv2.show();
                var mycode = document.createElement('div');
                mycode.innerHTML = '<pre><code data-language="json">' + JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2) + '</code></pre>';
                Rainbow.color(mycode, function() {
                    document.getElementById('mydiv2').appendChild(mycode)
                });
            } else {
                mydiv2.hide();

            }

            console.log(data);
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
        });

    });
```

Comment: what is `Rainbow` ??

Comment: Please clarify the wording of the problem too. I've read it 3 times and still am not sure what is being asked.

Comment: Rainbow is a code syntax highlighting! You go to https://craig.is/making/rainbows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have AJAX URL. I gave dummy data. It should work.

Every time, while showing you are appending the content with existing content. So it will repeat. So you have to remove the existing content in div and append it to div.

Add this line before appending

```
document.getElementById('mydiv2').innerHTML = '';
```

Then existing content will get cleared.

```js
$("button#liuyan").on("click", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

           data = {
           "name":"hello"
           }

            var mydiv2 = $("#mydiv2");

            if (mydiv2.css("display") === "none") {
                mydiv2.show();
                var mycode = document.createElement('div');
                mycode.innerHTML = '<pre><code data-language="json">' + JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2) + '</code></pre>';
                //Rainbow.color(mycode, function() {
                 document.getElementById('mydiv2').innerHTML = '';    
                 document.getElementById('mydiv2').appendChild(mycode)
                //});
            } else {
                mydiv2.hide();

            }

         //   console.log(data);
        //    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
       // });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="liuyan">Click</button>
<div id="mydiv2"></div>
```

Another Way:

You can make a call on ready function and show and hide when click on the button

Comment: Ok.Thank you very much!